# json.net required property not found in json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Json.net, I got a class as following

```
public class RecordAlias
    {   
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "eId", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string EntityId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "aId", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public string AliasId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "iSd", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

So that following json can be deserialized even through some items don't have property "iSd" in json string, I would expect a default value of that type should be populated if not present, for example, IsSelected should be false except last item

```
      [{
        "eId" : "30022004",
        "aId" : "1"
    }, {
        "eId" : "30021841",
        "aId" : "1"
    }, {
        "eId" : "30021848",
        "aId" : "1"
        "iSd" : true
    }
]
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not specifying `eId` in your JSON string, and it's set to be required.  You're passing `rId`...is this the same thing?

If I'm not understanding the question, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

**UPDATE**:
You're indicating that the `iSd` property is `AllowNull`.  You still have to specify a value for this property in your JSON string, but it can be null.  Per the JSON.NET [specs](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/):

> The property must be defined in JSON but can be a null value.

You need to specify a value for `iSd`...or mark `iSd` in your `JsonProperty` attribute as `DefaultValue`.  For `DefaultValue`, the [spec](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) says:

> The property is not required. The default state.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "iSd", Required = Required.Default)]
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake when copied pasted..i've updated my question

Comment: Some json strings doesn't have that property as the property is optional..how can make the class to accept a json string that doesn't have certain property value?

Comment: see my answer -- set the `JsonProperty` attribute's `Required` property to `Default`.

Answer (score 12):

I made a little table for the `Required` enum values and their effect based on [the `Required` documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm):

| Option | Must be present | Can be Null value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Required.Default` |  | ✓ |
| `Required.AllowNull` | ✓ | ✓ |
| `Required.Always` | ✓ |  |
| `Required.DisallowNull` |  |  |

In your case the `isD` is optional you should have used `Required.Default` (or `Required.DisallowNull`). Using `Required.AllowNull` also makes the `isD` mandatory and it thus throws the Exception when it's missing.

Note that in this case it makes no sense to differentiate between "Optional and may be null" (`Required.Default`) or "Optional but may not be null" (`Required.DisallowNull`) because `bool` is a value type that cannot be null. If you wanted to allow null values you need to use a nullable value type (`bool?`), however then the default value (when the value is not present) would be `null`, except when you set it manually (for example to `false`):

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "iSd", Required = Required.Default)]
public bool? IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the property a `bool` not a `string`.

Comment: sorry i made mistake when copied my class, i've updated my question