# c# parent child list add IDs

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have a parent child list which I get as JSON

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
       this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine I get a JSON that I will deserialize into

```
 string json = "json in here"

 List<Item> listItems = JsonConvert.Dezerialize<List<Item>>(json);
```

My question: how can I parse the `List<Item>` and add dynamically ID's to it so it will be something like this?

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
       this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The Id is the item Id (can be Guid for example) and ParentId is the Id of the parent for the item. If Item has no parent then ParentId is null. If ParentId is null Item is then top item. There can be more then one parent items.

Comment: just update your dto class with new property Id than update you data via set values and serialize it.
related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472486/json-net-required-property-not-found-in-json

Comment: Are you asking how to manually assign IDs after the object has been deserialized?  Doable with recursion, but what exactly are you looking to accomplish?  There's little guarantee that the same IDs will ever be applied to the same instances any time this is run, so they're not really *identifying* the elements.  What's the higher-order problem being solved?

Comment: Does `Name` are unique?

Comment: Each item contains a `List<Item>` ? This doesn't make sense to me.. So each `Item`'s `Items` contains one `Item` (itself)?

Comment: @cdsln: It's a tree structure.  Any given node has a collection of child nodes.

Comment: Exactly: it's a tree structure. Like your hdd. If you go to C:\ you will see all folders in there. These folders are the top nodes. Each top folder can have any number of subfolders and subfolders any number of subfolders and so forth...

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: No. Names are not unique like folders, can have a subfolder with the same name.

Comment: The JSON is already formatted as parent child. The only thing is that parents and children don't have ids and I need to add ids to them.

Comment: @David: I need to store this into a database table as parent child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can be Guid for example

That makes this *a lot* easier, since you don't have to keep track of which IDs have been used.  Now it's a simple job for recursion:

```
void SetIDs(Item item, string parentId)
{
    item.ParentId = parentId;
    item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    foreach (var i in item.Items)
        SetIDs(i, item.Id);
}
```

Then just call it with an initial empty ID for the top-level item (per your requirement that the top-level has a `null` parent ID):

```
SetIDs(someItem, null);
```

(If you did have to track the IDs, such as with an `int` for example, then you'd likely either be looking at a higher-scoped variable which can be tricky or `out` parameters or something of that nature which can be ugly.)